# asp.net page keeps reloading after js scrollIntoView()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an element on my cshtml page which I want to scroll to with `id="OtherInformationTitle"`

I also have a link with an on-click event to trigger the scrolling `<a asp-page="" asp-route-culture="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name" id="PrivacyOtherInformationLink" onclick="privacyPageScrollToElement()">@_loc[Model.PrivacyOtherInformationLink]</a>`

and a javascript file called `privacyPageScrollToElement.js` containing the following code:

```
function privacyPageScrollToElement() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("OtherInformationTitle");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

My script is registered at the bottom of my cshtml page

```
</body>
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/nonmenuactive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/privacyPageScrollToElement.js"></script>
}
```

When I click the link, the page scrolls to the element, but then the page instantly reloads/refreshes back at the top of the page. I have also tried changing my js file to the below, but this scrolls to the element on page load (But does not jump back):

```
function privacyPageScrollToElement() {
    updateUI();
}

$(function () {

    var elmnt = document.getElementById("OtherInformationTitle");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView();

});
```

So it appears like my click event is scrolling to the element, then the page is refreshing. How can I get it to scroll on-click and stay there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by removing **asp-page="" asp-route-culture="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name"** from the anchor tag:

```
<a asp-page="" asp-route-culture="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name" id="PrivacyOtherInformationLink" onclick="privacyPageScrollToElement()">@_loc[Model.PrivacyOtherInformationLink]</a>
```

And replacing it with **href="javascript:void(0)"**:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="PrivacyOtherInformationLink" onclick="privacyPageScrollToElement()">@_loc[Model.PrivacyOtherInformationLink]</a>
```